# App freezes receiving Bluetooth data from ESP32

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app that sends and receives data from ESP32. I can send a String to ESP32 and my app has to show data from it. The problem is when I receive data from ESP32, the app freezes and doesn't show the data in EditText. If I turn the Bluettoh off, the data comes and show in the app.

In the Logcat, I can see the String that I send and receive properly from ESP32.

Why the app freezes and doesn't show the message but in Logcat I can see? Can anyone help me with any solution?

````java
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private Handler handler; // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service


        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream
        private Object address;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
            // member streams are final.
            try {
                //tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
            }
            

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }


        public void run() {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[15];
            int bytes;

            while (true) {
                try {

                    bytes = mmInStream.available();

                    if (bytes == 15) {
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Bytes: " + bytes);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Buffer: " + buffer);



                            String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                            Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);

                            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    textView.setText(incomingMessage);
                                }
                            });
                        }


                            

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            public void enviar(byte[] bytes) {
                String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
                Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(bytes);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }```
````

Comment: I found the issue. In My function which call a button, that was a line calling the run() and for this reason the app freezes when a pressed the button. I remove it and works properly.

Like: 'connectedThread.run();'